# gitlab-runner and git, error: detected dubious ownership in repository

Tags: git, gitlab, centos7, gitlab-ci, gitlab-runner

После последнего обновления git получаю ошибку:

```
fatal: detected dubious ownership in repository at
git config --global --add safe.directory /home/backend
```

Пробовал выполнять комманду, не помогло, ошибка та же.
Искал похожие ошибки, нашел тему на stackoverflow.com

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72978485/git-submodule-update-failed-with-fatal-detected-dubious-ownership-in-repositor

Но ни один ответ не помог. Ошибка осталась та же.
Сервер Centos 7. Runner и git установлены от root. Проект также клонировался и запускается от root. Это единственный проект на сервере. SELinux пробовал отключать

Можете помочь с проблемой?

Comment: на Stack Overflow на русском вопросы принято задавать **только на русском языке**. Пожалуйста, переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык или воспользуйтесь Stack Overflow на английском.

Comment: не клонируйте и не запускайте проекты от root